# How to send Selenium login credentials to PDFKit

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, pdfkit

I am using Selenium, Python, ChromeDriver and PDFKit to convert the data in the browser to PDF. But seems like PDFKit is not getting the credentials from Selenium so it's coming as "unauthorised". Please find the code below.

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    import pdfkit
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    import time
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    chrome_path = r"C:\chrome\chromedriver.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
    driver.get("https://test.test.com/login")
    time.sleep(5)
    username = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
    password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
    username.send_keys("admin")
    password.send_keys("admin")
    time.sleep(5)
    submit_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/cd-authenticate/div/div/div/cd-login/div[1]/form/button')
    submit_button.click()
    time.sleep(5)
pdfkit.from_url('https://test.test.com/comp/export?format=csv&filters=start_time:2018-03-04T00%3A00%3A00Z+end_time:2018-03-15T18%3A29%3A59Z+node_name:abcdef','out.pdf')
```

Comment: Are you getting an errormessage?

Comment: YES Exit with code 1 due to network error: AuthenticationRequiredError

Comment: Why would pdfkit get the credentials from Selenium? It’s a completely separate library.